# Craft Commerce PayPal Checkout: Error: Expected an order id to be passed

Tags: craft4, commerce4

I am having big trouble getting the PayPal checkout plugin to work. I am using this code:

```
        {% namespace cart.gateway.handle|commercePaymentFormNamespace %}
            {{ cart.gateway.getPaymentFormHtml({
                currency: cart.paymentCurrency,
                'buyer-country': cart.billingAddress.countryCode,
                locale: lang == 'de' ? 'de_CH' : 'en_GB',
            })|raw }}
        {% endnamespace %}
```

That displays the PayPal form correctly:

[image]

But as soon as I click on one of the buttons, I get a JS alert saying "**Error: Expected an order id to be passed**".

I think the Gateway is correctly set up. When I enter wrong data, the buttons don't show up. Here is my setup:

[image]

Content of my `.env`:

```
PAYPAL_ENABLED=true
PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID=AQxp4QbX2hmlqHtpJ_...
PAYPAL_SECRET=EBPo6JbLQ0bt0-...
PAYPAL_SANDBOX=true
```

Any hints and comments welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by following the developer's guide to create an app with dedicated credentials (https://github.com/craftcms/commerce-paypal-checkout/blob/develop/README.md#creating-paypal-rest-api-credentials) and deactivating "Payouts" on PayPal app and enabling "Log in with PayPal"